# Object moved here CURL php

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

someone help me about curl php, with localhost it working, but build on WEB is not working with code:

```
public function curl()
    {
        $this->channel = curl_init();
        // you might want the headers for http codes
        curl_setopt( $this->channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
        curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
        curl_setopt( $this->channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );   
        curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60); 
        curl_setopt( $this->channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($this->channel,CURLOPT_ENCODING,"gzip"); 
        curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    }
```

i build to web and error: "Object moved to here", but i use xampp localhost is working.

Comment: You should try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);` since we don't know what actually happens as you don't provide the target URL.

Comment: i try, but it still error: "Object moved to here"

Comment: why you have duplicate options set?

Comment: i get from internet, with localhost is working, so i think duplication not problem

Comment: It's not but there's no reason to keep it.

Comment: Can you give us the URL so we can test and see why it does that?

Answer (score 1):

You can set return transfer curl option. Please check [php_docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more information.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You missing more option to curl execution. like `exec, close, url` etc. Where is `CURLOPT_URL` you doesn't intialize a url to post. Also try to remove duplicate option set.

```
public function curl() {
    $url = 'your url';
    $this->channel = curl_init($url);
    // you might want the headers for http codes
    curl_setopt( $this->channel, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
    curl_setopt( $this->channel, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );   
    curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60); 
    curl_setopt( $this->channel, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($this->channel, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    // Execute curl.
    $result = curl_exec ($this->channel);
    // Check what exectly curl is doing.
    print_r(curl_getinfo($this->channel));
    // CLOSE CURL
    curl_close ($this->channel);
}
```

You can check your curl exec info by `curl_getinfo($this->channel)` before curl close. also set a output for result.